# comparing data stored in two m-files

Tags: matlab

how to retrieve the data from m.file into another m.file?
    How to compare these two files?

Comment: Since m-files are usually Matlab functions it's a little unusual for them to contain data.  Do you mean .mat files perhaps ?

Answer (score 2):

Referring to these [posts](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/161225) matlab comes with a diff tool on board, offering an API.

```
com.mathworks.mde.difftool.DiffReportGroup.getInstance.showFileDiff(...
     filePathLeft, filePathRight, numColumns);
showUnsavedChangesDiff(filePathLeft,textString,numColumns)
```

See the referred posts for further details.